# How to use RESTfulWebServiceClient for php server in CN1

Tags: codenameone

I want to generate the code for the server in php and use it as the backend instead of webservices in java. I noticed that, webservices Wizard in CN1 generated details on the server side. In my own case I want to create the server in php and use RESTfulWebServiceClient to point to the url.

1. Pls how do I go about this?
2. Is there any webservice Wizard that can generate the php server like java in netbeans?
3. In the auto re-new subscription in in-app purchase can I interact with the mysql database without using RESTfulWebServiceClient? 
   Thanks for your response

   I have created the webservices in php and used the url in codename one. I was able to use the url to submit receipt into the database. see the image below

[image]

I still have challenges, the error code below was generated

```
 [EDT] 0:0:0,0 - Codename One revisions: 3dc2fe6c4df57ff264ea094d13e0275639b780862293

[EDT] 0:0:0,0 - Receipts were last refreshed at Fri Mar 17 07:30:21 WAT 2017 so we won't refetch.
WARNING: Apple will no longer accept http URL connections from applications you tried to connect to http://slimapp/api/customer/add to learn more check out https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html
[Task Thread] 0:0:0,417 - Expected null for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 44 buffer: 
[Task Thread] 0:0:0,417 - Expected true for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 47 buffer: 
[Task Thread] 0:0:0,417 - Expected null for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 49 buffer: 
[Task Thread] 0:0:0,417 - Expected null for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 52 buffer: 
[Task Thread] 0:0:0,417 - Expected true for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 57 buffer: l
[Task Thread] 0:0:0,417 - Expected null for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 70 buffer: 1048l
[Task Thread] 0:0:0,417 - Expected null for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 88 buffer: 1048l
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1048le"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:286)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.parseJSON(JSONParser.java:427)
    at com.codename1.ws.RESTfulWebServiceClient.lambda$null$6(RESTfulWebServiceClient.java:204)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display$1.run(Display.java:806)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
WARNING: Apple will no longer accept http URL connections from applications you tried to connect to http://slimapp/api/customer/add to learn more check out https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-http-urls.html
[Task Thread] 0:0:8,888 - Expected null for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 44 buffer: 
[Task Thread] 0:0:8,888 - Expected true for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 47 buffer: 
[Task Thread] 0:0:8,888 - Expected null for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 49 buffer: 
[Task Thread] 0:0:8,888 - Expected null for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 52 buffer: 
[Task Thread] 0:0:8,888 - Expected true for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 57 buffer: l
[Task Thread] 0:0:8,888 - Expected null for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 70 buffer: 1048l
[Task Thread] 0:0:8,888 - Expected null for key value while parsing JSON token at row: 1 column: 88 buffer: 1048l
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1048le"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:286)
    at com.codename1.io.JSONParser.parseJSON(JSONParser.java:427)
    at com.codename1.ws.RESTfulWebServiceClient.lambda$null$6(RESTfulWebServiceClient.java:204)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display$1.run(Display.java:806)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

After subscribing and I press Syns Receipts. Subscribe to remove ads is still there. Pls help Thanks

This is my php webserver code.

```
    <?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;



$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->get('/api/customers', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
echo "customers";

  //  Get All customers
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM receipts";

  try{
$db = new db();

$db = $db->connect();
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$customers = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $db = null;
  echo json_encode($customers);

  }catch(PDOException $e){
echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
  }



});





$app->get('/api/customers/{transactionId}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
echo "customers";
$id = $request ->getAttribute("transactionId");
  //  Get single  customers
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM receipts where transaction_id = $id";

  try{
$db = new db();

$db = $db->connect();
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$customers = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $db = null;
  echo json_encode($customers);

  }catch(PDOException $e){
echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
  }



});




//add a user
$app->post('/api/customer/add', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
//echo "customers";





$transactionId = $request->getParam('transactionId');

$sku = $request->getParam('sku');
$purchaseDate = $request->getParam('purchaseDate');
$orderData = $request->getParam('orderData');
$storeCode = $request->getParam('storeCode');

echo "emmy ";


 // (:transactionId,:sku,:purchaseDate,:orderData,:storeCode)";

// 'transactionid' 

 $sql = "INSERT INTO receipts(transaction_id,sku,purchase_date,order_data,store_code)VALUES
          (:transactionid,:sku,:purchaseDate,:orderData,:storeCode)";





  try{
$db = new db();

$db = $db->connect();
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);



$stmt->bindParam(':transactionid', $transactionId);
$stmt->bindParam(':sku', $sku);
$stmt->bindParam(':purchaseDate', $purchaseDate);
$stmt->bindParam(':orderData', $orderData);
$stmt->bindParam(':storeCode', $storeCode);






$stmt->execute();

echo '{"notice": {"text": "customar added"}';


  }catch(PDOException $e){
echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
  }



});
```

This is my url  and part of my code in codename name:

```
 private static final String receiptsEndpoint = "http://slimapp/api/customers";
  private static final String receiptsEndpoint2 = "http://slimapp/api/customer/add";


private ReceiptStore createReceiptStore() {
    return new ReceiptStore() {

        RESTfulWebServiceClient client = createRESTClient(receiptsEndpoint);

      RESTfulWebServiceClient client2 = createRESTClient(receiptsEndpoint2);

        @Override
        public void fetchReceipts(SuccessCallback<Receipt[]> callback) {
            RESTfulWebServiceClient.Query query = new RESTfulWebServiceClient.Query() {

                @Override
                protected void setupConnectionRequest(RESTfulWebServiceClient client, ConnectionRequest req) {
                    super.setupConnectionRequest(client, req);
       //  req.setPost(true);
     // req.setHttpMethod("post"); //Change to GET if necessary
                    req.setUrl(receiptsEndpoint);
                }



                protected void setupConnectionRequest2(RESTfulWebServiceClient client2, ConnectionRequest req2) {
                    super.setupConnectionRequest(client, req2);
        req2.setPost(true);
     req2.setHttpMethod("post"); //Change to GET if necessary
                    req2.setUrl(receiptsEndpoint2);
                }


            };


            client.find(query, rowset->{
                List<Receipt> out = new ArrayList<Receipt>();
                for (Map m : rowset) {


                    Result res = Result.fromContent(m);
                    Receipt r = new Receipt();
                    r.setTransactionId(res.getAsString("transactionId"));



                     System.out.println(r.getTransactionId()+"  ko");
                    r.setPurchaseDate(new Date(res.getAsLong("purchaseDate")));
                    r.setQuantity(1);
                    r.setSku(res.getAsString("sku"));

                    if (m.containsKey("cancellationDate") && m.get("cancellationDate") != null) {
                        r.setCancellationDate(new Date(res.getAsLong("cancellationDate")));
                    }
                    if (m.containsKey("expiryDate") && m.get("expiryDate") != null) {
                        r.setExpiryDate(new Date(res.getAsLong("expiryDate")));
                    }
                    out.add(r);

                }
                callback.onSucess(out.toArray(new Receipt[out.size()]));
            }); 


        }

        @Override
        public void submitReceipt(Receipt r, SuccessCallback<Boolean> callback) {

              Map m = new HashMap();
            m.put("transactionId", r.getTransactionId());
          m.put("sku", r.getSku());
            m.put("purchaseDate", r.getPurchaseDate().getTime());
            m.put("orderData", r.getOrderData());
           m.put("storeCode", r.getStoreCode());

       System.out.println(r.getTransactionId());
            client2.create(m, callback);



    }
};
            }
```

pls help to review my code in above what I am missing maybe in php webserver code or in codename one code. I was able to subscribe and receive the message that the subscription was succesfull and the records was inserted into the database,  when I click on Syns Receipts Button, No receipt was updated and the record goes to the database. Pls help, I dont know what is going wrong

Comment: FYI You pressed edit on my answer instead of your question

Answer (score 0):

Our webservice wizard expects a Java server and doesn't generate PHP code.

You can use any restful service from Codename One by using `ConnectionRequest` and invoking a URL with `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` & `DELETE`.

See the [developer guide section on networking](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html). If you create a webservice in PHP and have the curl usage I can help with the Codename One equivalent.

Comment: Sir. pls I have edited my questions. You may check for the proper guide sir. Thanks

Comment: The number 1048le is invalid the JSON you are getting from the webservice isn't valid JSON. I suggest using the Network Monitor tool in the simulator where you can see requests going in-out and see the JSON

Comment: I found this on the response body in the network monitor :{"error": {"text": SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'TRANSACTION_ID' cannot be null}

Comment: when I click on subscription button, I found this on the request in post body:  {
  "purchaseDate": 1490001720982,
  "orderData": "",
  "sku": "iapdemo.noads.month.auto",
  "transactionId": "cn1-iap-sim-8c008610-3b3b-43ed-9ee3-2dab830026a5",
  "storeCode": "simulator"
}

Comment: That doesn't seem to correspond with the error you posted in the message.  The error mentioned trying to parse a number "1048le".  That doesn't appear in that JSON.

Comment: That's invalid JSON from the server. Notice that SQLSTATE needs to be preceded by quotes. Try pasting it into http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I have resolved the issue of the json, the root cause is, I used   req.setPost(true);
         req.setHttpMethod("post"); when I remove these it does not bring the error again.

Comment: I have moved on to another stage which is a little bit confusing. I have pasted both my server code in php and and codename one as edit in above. pls help me to archive this task

Comment: You should file a new issue and ideally also tag it PHP as I don't know PHP and other developers won't notice the edit so won't be able to help. It's also harder for me to read the question when it's edited and see what's still an open or resolved issue so I have no idea what's being asked now